# Write to a file identified by its Url in pure javascript

Tags: javascript

I would need to add data to a text file from javascript.
I've found the following code :

```
var file = showFilePicker(window, "", Components.interfaces.nsIFilePicker.modeSave, "", function(fp) {return fp.file;});
var outputStream = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/network/file-output-stream;1"].createInstance( Components.interfaces.nsIFileOutputStream);
outputStream.init(file, 0x02 | 0x08 | 0x20, 0644, 0);
outputStream.write(someText, someText.length);
outputStream.close();
```

However it takes a file chosen by the user thanks to a file picker.
In my case, I'd like to write to a text file identified by its URL (for example : C://.../text.js)

Comment: I hope this is still impossible, so that not any arbitrary website can write to my harddrive.

Comment: @Sirko, don't worry, fortunately it's still impossible to do that.

Comment: That piece of code looks like code for a Firefox addon. The addons are written in JavaScript but this is JavaScript running in a context **different** from the context in which JavaScript embedded in a page runs.

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/file-writer-api/

Answer (score 0):

This probably isn't possible in a browser because of security restrictions. You can do it with NodeJS, though.